# what's a .TIF file and how do I use it?

Tags: pdf, images

I have scanned In around 300 pages of an old archive map for my work experience. I divided them by sub maps so I ended up with 13 `.PDF` files.

As of now I started converting the first file to images using PDF-XChange viewer thinking they would become `.jpeg` files. but they did not, they became `.TIF` files (`yes those are all capital letters, at least in window XP's properties tab`)

Immagine TIF

[image]

So how can I use them?

I want to be able to combine all the 300 images I got into new .pdf files after I did some photo "enchanting" like cutting out the white areas or changing the contrast. Can this be done with .TIF files?

I found this article on combining multiple images into one pdf: [Link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11163/how-do-i-combine-two-or-more-images-to-get-a-single-pdf-file) Does this work with TIF files?

Comment: It could be [TIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format). Try opening it in Paint(or equivalent), if it works, its an image file (and file association is borked on your system).

Comment: From the second line of the article: `"TIF" and "TIFF" redirect here.`. I think we are talking about the same file

Comment: olden windows xp days, I just miss them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TIFF file is a high quality `Tagged Image File Format` - further reading [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format). It can have several "pages" and has support for layers, similar to a PDF.

There are many image applications that can open TIFF files. You can open it in Windows XP using `Windows Picture and Fax Viewer`.

There are many solutions for converting a TIFF to PDF as well as editing, some online based ones and some downloaded. To prevent too much information that will go out of date, I suggest searching for a `TIFF to PDF converter`, or `TIF Image Editor`, or check within your scanner software for this option, as many scanners will have the option to scan directly to JPG/TIFF/PDF. I personally use `Irfanview` which can handle almost every image format I can throw at it, but there are a lot of other utilities out there.

Comment: is the `Windows Picture` you talk about the same as windows photo viewer that comes with XP or is it a different program? Windows photo viewer cant show the files.

Comment: @CoderGuy Assuming the images are okay, it's called `Windows Picture and Fax viewer` and may not be the same, I'm not sure what program you're trying to use. Under 'Open With', choose this option: http://www.faxpipe.com/images/xp/open_with.gif

Comment: I use the program that comes with windows XP called Windows photo viewer. which is a simple photo viewer that comes with windows as a standard

Comment: @CoderGuy That is a different utility - both come with Windows XP, although I would expect that to open it okay also, it's possible the conversion to TIFF didn't work properly. I've added one example utility you can try in my answer.

Comment: I'll convert them to jpegs then. I can't convert TIF files to pdf files with my converter.

Comment: Assuming that your documents are essentially printed text, never, ever, ever use JPEG. JPEG creates horrendous artefacts when it encounters strong contrasts, which hurts readabiltiy. Use TIFF or PNG with lossless compression.